# iPad app designing

Tags: ios, ipad

I need to create an app for ipad.Its something like the contacts app in ipad.(like an open book)[image]

My doubts are whether they are using split view or two different views.
If splitview is used,how could we increase its width and style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background can be just a chunk of graphic or a picture. On top of that you'd add your own or Apples UI elements.

Each functional area should probably be implemented as a separate subview, ie. the `UITableView` on the left, the index on the right and so forth.

In your words - implement it as separate views not a split view.

Answer (score 7):

You can tell that they are not using a split view controller by turning the screen vertically: split view moves the master into a popover; contacts simply rotates, without popping the master portion out. I think that they use a single, highly customized, view for the contacts.

Comment: Not always, Settings app use a portrait UISplitViewController... in any case this must be some kind of private api not avaliable to users.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something like that (don't know why you would... the Contacts app is horrible) then you're going to look past the default set of UI elements provided to you by Apple.

UIViewController, UITableView are really the only two things you'd be reusing for something like that.